# mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, connection

I am trying to connect mysql using xampp php myAdmin.

User `root` is there in mysql db by default.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $dbCon=@mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '');
    if (!$dbCon)
    {
        echo('<p> '.mysql_error().'</p>');
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        if(!@mysql_select_db("crs",$dbCon))
     {
        die( "<p>".mysql_error()."</p>");
     }
    }

    $qry="Create Table Courses( cCode VarChar(5) Not NULL Primary Key, cTitle VarChar(50) Not NULL, CH INT)";

    if(@mysql_query($qry))
    {
        echo('<p>Courses Table has been created</p>');
    }
    else 
    {
        echo('<p>Courses Table can not be created due to' .mysql_error(). '</p>');

    }
    $qry="Insert INTO Courses Values('C001','Intro to computing',4)";
        if (@mysql_query($qry))
        {
            echo('<p>C001 is inserted </p>');
        }
        else
        {
            echo('<p>Courses Table cannot be created due to'.mysql_error().'</p>');

        }
        $qry="Insert INTO Courses Values ('C002', 'Programming Fundamentals',4), ('C003', 'Object Oriented Programming',4), ('C004', 'Operating Systems',4), ('C005', 'Data Structures and Algorithms',4)";
        if(@mysql_query($qry))
        {
        echo('<p>4 Rows have been inserted</p>');
        }
        else

            echo('<p>Multiple Rows cant be inserted due to'.mysql_error().'</p>')           



?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code as such. However mysql has been set up with root needing a password to connect from local host, which you haven't go in your call to mysql_connect. Without a way of connecting as an admin user or someone remembering how they set mysql up, can't really help you.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using a password and the error means that the user root has no access or has no access because it needs a password.